# how to make run cron on OSX 10.6.2?

Tags: macos, cron

Note:
this question is not about **how to edit cron tab but how to make cron work**

---

1. I edited my cron using `env EDITOR=joe crontab -e`
2. I entered `1    *   *   *   *   echo 'test' > /Users/radek/Backup/rationalvmware/test.txt` and it does nothing although the cron is set up **correctly**. Checked via Cronnix and viewed the cron in /var/cron/tabs. Editing crontab using Cronnix gives me the same results.

If I run `echo 'test' > /Users/radek/Backup/rationalvmware/test.txt` manually it creates a files as expected so I assume that the command I provide to cron is correct one.

Is there **anything special** I have to do to make cron work on OSX? How can I check it the the cron is running.

What's the equivalent of /var/log/messages on OSX? I can see in messages on SuSE that cron works.

Comment: As an aside: note that `cron` runs in a different environment than your own test command would. For example: you might often need absolute paths.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I doubt you waited until 1 minute past the hour for your test. To run *every* minute:

```
0-59 * * * * echo 'test' > /Users/radek/Backup/rationalvmware/test.txt
```

Comment: From Mavericks or later, an alternative sending yourself a notification `0-59 * * * * osascript -e "display notification \"$(date)\" with title \"Cron test\""`

Answer (score 10):

The cron utility is launched by launchd when it sees the existence of `/etc/crontab` or files in `/usr/lib/cron/tabs`. **There should be no need to start it manually**. (See the [man pages](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/cron.8.html).)

To see logs of OS X, you can use Console Utility.

Comment: On Mt. Lion that location is actually symlinked several times, leading ultimately to: `/private/var/at/tabs/`, FYI

Answer (score 9):

Two other ways are to use:

```
*/1 * * * * echo 'test' > /Users/radek/Backup/rationalvmware/test.txt
```

or

```
* * * * * echo 'test' > /Users/radek/Backup/rationalvmware/test.txt
```

These both run every minute.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to set your `$EDITOR` variable to something reasonable, since what you did set it to something you don't want. Set it like this:

```
EDITOR=joe
```

You can change `joe` to another text editor, such as `nano`or `vim`.

Then, you'll want to edit your `crontab`, which is done like so:

```
crontab -e
```

Then you'll put in the text for `cron` to use.

Comment: I updated my question. I can edit the cron the way I do it but the cron doesn't run....

Comment: There's no reason `joe` couldn't be used. The key is that `crontab -e` is used.

Comment: joe is the best

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use cron on Mountain Lion you should take a look here: https://coderwall.com/p/ry9jwg or just open terminal and run `sudo touch /etc/crontab`. After that your jobs in /usr/lib/cron/tabs should be handled by cron.